# Resize Array By Last and not by First in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, resize

I have an Array of Class elements, and by an int variable i need to resize this array to the last X elements.

So for example i have an array with:

```
Array[0] = Msg1
Array[1] = Msg2
Array[2] = Msg3
Array[3] = Msg4
Array[4] = Msg5
Array[5] = Msg6
Array[6] = Msg7
Array[7] = Msg8
Array[8] = Msg9
Array[9] = Msg10
```

and i need to have only the last 8 elements in the array.

i cannot use the Array.Resize function because the result would be:

```
Array[0] = Msg1
Array[1] = Msg2
Array[2] = Msg3
Array[3] = Msg4
Array[4] = Msg5
Array[5] = Msg6
Array[6] = Msg7
Array[7] = Msg8
```

and i need something like this:

```
Array[0] = Msg3
Array[1] = Msg4
Array[2] = Msg5
Array[3] = Msg6
Array[4] = Msg7
Array[5] = Msg8
Array[6] = Msg9
Array[7] = Msg10
```

How can i do this? i hope my problem is clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With LINQ:

```
array = array.Skip(array.Length - 8).ToArray();
```

Wthout LINQ:

```
int[] temp = new int[8];
Array.Copy(array, array.Length - temp.Length, temp, 0, temp.Length);
array = temp;
```

Comment: Ooh Linq! Probably better to Skip(array.length - 8)?

Comment: Sorry, i'm in WinMo, so i cannot use external collections.. and my array class don't have a Skip function :(

Comment: @Leen15: Does my update help you? See the final suggestion (refresh the page if you can't see it).

Answer (score 4):

Create a new Array, then do 
`Array.Copy()`.
Or, with LINQ, you can do
`array.Skip(array.Length - 8).Take(8).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Do they have to be in the same order?

How about something like

```
Reverse(Array);
Resize(ref Array, 8)?
```

Heck, you could reverse again to get your order back

Comment: i cannot Reverse the array, in the array there are Messages in order by Date.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're probably using the wrong collection. From your example it looks like a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or a [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) would be better choices, both of which would make your operation much easier, even trivial AND both have been part of the .NET FCL since 2.0. (No need for a specialized collections library.)

For a Queue collection you could simply call [Dequeue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1c8bzx97%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) n-times and with a LinkedList you could call [RemoveFirst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms132181%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) n-times giving you your final result.

And besides trimming the beginning of the collection you will be using other LinkedList or Queue operations which will probably be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Many functions that take arrays as parameters have overloads that take additional parameters such as a `startIndex` along with either a `length`/`count` or an `endIndex`.  The second parameter is sometimes optional, since the length or endIndex can be inferred using the `Array.Length` property.

For example:

```
SomeFunction<T>(T[] array, int startIndex, int length)
```

or

```
SomeFunction<T>(T[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

Just throwing this out there; perhaps this is an option for you.